# Git: How to change origin on locally cloned branch

Tags: git

I have a front-end Sass framework I am building on my local drive.  I started this project by cloning a different project that is also on my local drive.

Now I need this framework to be an independent copy from that other master.

The `.git/config` for this framework:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = S:/grunt-test
    fetch = +refs/heads/ruby-sass-susy:refs/remotes/origin/ruby-sass-susy
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/ruby-sass-susy
```

How do I safely modify this so that this framework completely disconnects from the original repo?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following two commands and set `[NEW_SRC]` to the location of your new repository:

```
git remote rm origin 
git remote add origin [NEW_SRC]
```

This will change your .git/config file and remove the reference to the old repository. Of course, you don't need to set a new `origin`.

If you have any tracking branches for this origin, you might also want to untrack those with: `git branch -d -r origin/<remote branch name>`

Comment: Thanks, the new origin of the framework is now itself.   Do I specify that with the path to itself?  ie  `git remote add origin N:\_base-frameworks\libsass-susy'

Comment: You would only set the origin if you want to push to that other repository. Otherwise you don't need to set an origin.

Comment: In the master branch of my framework - a Git status tells me 'Your branch is ahead of origin/ruby-sass-susy' by 20 commits'.    Then when I run `git remote rm origin` I get the error `fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files'.

Comment: You can use `git branch -d -r origin/ruby-sass-susy` to remove the tracking of the branch.

Comment: Running that command gave me "Your branch is based on 'origin/ruby-sass-susy', but the upstream is gone.  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)."    At that point `git branch --unset-upstream` removed the error message and it all looks clean.   The `.git/config` now has a [branch "master"] section that is empty.   Assuming this is what is supposed to happen,  looks like this worked thanks